# general error: Cannot open CSV file SAP HANA import

Tags: csv, jdbc, hana

```
IMPORT FROM CSV FILE 'C:\Users\mypc\IdeaProjects\Loadorcle\new\emp.csv' INTO RIGHTDATA.Employees1 WITH SKIP FIRST 1 ROW RECORD DELIMITED BY '\n' FIELD DELIMITED BY '`'
```

When i run the above query i get the exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [2]:
>   general error: Cannot open CSV file,
>   C:\Users\mypc\IdeaProjects\Loadorcle\new\emp.csv

the csv file is in a directory new under the project folder.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Is this file on the **server**, and if so has the user account running SAP Hana access to this location?

Comment: no file is in the local system @MarkRotteveel

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that file needs to be local to the server.

Comment: so local file cant be imported to sap hana table. Is that what you say? @MarkRotteveel

Comment: I don't know, probably not like this. I don't know SAP Hana specifically, but usually these types of statements are sent to the server to handle, so it cannot access files local to the client.

Answer (score 2):

The address on the **server** is not valid. Thus it gives the error.

If the file is local, you can do this in HANA Studio.

```
File -> Import -> SAP HANA Content - Data from Local File -> Next
```

And follow the lead to import the file.

Or you can upload the file to the server, and specify the full path in the sql.

Or make the local computer accessible in the server or mount to the server, then you can write sql like

```
IMPORT FROM CSV FILE '12.34.56.78:/path/to/csv' ...
IMPORT FROM CSV FILE '/mnt/yourmachine/path/to/csv' ...
```